# Ubuntu 13.10 freezes/crashes when suspended/hibernating

Tags: 13.10, suspend, freeze, hibernate

Hardware: Gateway FX 7805u

OS: Ubuntu 13.10 64bit

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop and am having an issue where the OS will lockup and freeze when entering suspend/hibernation. The screen is black and nothing will bring it out of suspension, IE mouse, keyboard, etc. Only way I've found to bring it out is to do a hard shutdown and reboot. I have seen where this is a known bug, but was wondering if there is a definitive fix or workaround for this issue. I did a search here and on Google but founding nothing solid so I wanted to ask to see if there was a known and up to date way to resolve this issue. I'm not too familiar with Linux, but I am willing to do the work to get this fixed. I have been nothing but satisfied with the OS and plan to stay with it for quite some time. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. If there is any other info that would be needed to have a better idea on a solution to this problem, I'll be more than happy to provide it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try to install and enable the recommended proprietary drivers for your graphics card.

See also: Step 2. Enable Additional Drivers on [10 Things To Do After Installing Ubuntu 13.10 | OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/10/10-things-installing-ubuntu-13-10)

Comment: I'll be trying that and report back whether that worked or not.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers suggested for my GTS 9800M card and haven't had one lockup since then.